# Creating terminal help text in JS

Tags: javascript, terminal, command, line, gulp

I am using Gulp to create a bunch of tasks for a project I have and when you type gulp I would like to show some instructions on the terminal to show people the commands they can Run and what they do.
I didn't want to use console.log because it blends in and I wanted to give bolds and styles to the lettering.

I was searching for a way to do that but I couldn't find any that worked properly, does anyone know?

Examples of people that have this is Yeoman and Foundation for Apps CLI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to avoid using `console.log` you can use the underlying standard output, accessible in node through `process.stdout`

https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_stdout

The example provided in that link is the actual definition of console.log in node:

```
console.log = function(d) {
    process.stdout.write(d + '\n');
};
```

For colouring and styling your strings you could use [cli-color](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cli-color) or [chalk](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chalk).

Comment: process.stdout and cli-color worked great ! Thank you

Comment: I'm glad I could help. If this post answered your question, please mark it as the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

you can either use [gulp-help](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-help), which gives you ability to provided even details to be printed for a given task... or use [gulp-task-linking](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-task-listing) which prints tasks as main tasks & sub-tasks

visit the link to know all the options that they provide...